# Disable guest checkout spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Is there any way to disable the functionality which allows guests to make orders in spree? I searched around but couldn't seem to see anything, also no settings in the admin panel.

Is there any proper way to do this or will I have to go through the code and rip stuff out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `allow_guest_checkout` preference to change the default setting with checkout.

You can set this preference false to disable guest checkout in spree.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this still working as of 3.7.3 (the latest version)? I'm not having success when I put this in my config file, and furthermore when I search the spree repository the only time that `allow_guest_checkout` seems to come up is in the setting definition file and in markdown files...which seems to mean spree sets the default for this setting but never uses it (?)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change this functionality by setting `allow_guest_checkout` to `false`.
Go to config/initializers/spree.rb,
then insert

> config.allow_guest_checkout = false

see https://github.com/spree/spree-guides/blob/master/content/developer/core/preferences.md